# How to handle the structure of page/taxonomy/post without making wordpress get confused with the url

Tags: php

Not sure how my title should be.

My problem started when i saw that pagination doesn't work and it redirects to  404 error. After reading many posts, the reason pagination doesn't works is because i have a page called "Watches" and my custom post type is also "watches" and that can't be the same because wordpress gets confused with the url.

So i want somehow to change my custom post's name so it won't be any conflict.

I have the below :

Watches : **custom post type** (mysite.com/watches/rolex/title_of_watch) - single

Watches : **page** (mysite.com/watches) - show all terms of taxonomy "taxwatches"

taxwatches :  **taxonomy** (**rolex** is a term for example)

I use rewrite on posts so i can have this structure -> 
site.com/custom_post_type/term/post_title

Currently my page "watches" and custom post type "watches" is the same.

Below is the code for registering the custom post type :

```
$args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'watches/%taxwatches%', 'with_front' => false,  ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'taxonomies'         => array( 'taxwatches'),
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes')
    );

    register_post_type( 'watches', $args );
```

Below is the code for taxonomy :

```
   $args = array(
        'public'            => true,
        'has_archive'       => true,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => __('taxwatches', 'Theme'), 'with_front' => false, ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'taxwatches', array( 'taxwatches' ), $args );
```

And that is a filter to use the rewrite of url :

```
function products_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%taxwatches%' ) ) {
        $term = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'taxwatches');

        if (is_array($term)) {
            $post_link = str_replace('%taxwatches%', strtolower(array_pop($term)->name), $post_link);
        }
    }


    return $post_link;
}
```

I have tried different things but it got me confused so decided to ask a question. Any ideas or reference that could help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, i added to functions.php the below code :

This code checks if current page is page or not. If it's not page that means it is

mysite.com/watches/term/

otherwise if it is page

mysite.com/watches

So problem solved.

```
add_filter('template_include', 'template_include');

function template_include($template) {

    $post_type = get_post_type();


   if(!is_page() && $post_type == null && !is_archive())
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/taxonomy.php';

    return $template;

}
```

Comment: And now paginations works just fine.